# Alpine Linux - javac not found

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an Alpine Linux image that contains OpenJDK. The Java runtime (`java`) is installed, but the Java compiler (`javac`) isn't. I expect the compiler to come with OpenJDK, like how it is when installing via `apt` or `yum`.

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash openjdk8

RUN java -version
RUN javac --version
```

When building the Dockerfile, the following error is returned:
`The command '/bin/sh -c javac -version' returned a non-zero code: 127`

How can I have the Java compiler available on Alpine?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
FROM alpine:latest
USER root

RUN apk update
RUN apk fetch openjdk8
RUN apk add openjdk8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

RUN java -version
RUN javac -version
```

Comment: My problem is that I can always run `java -version` but elasticsearch 6.5 does not see it.. I can even run it as the elasticsearch user and works but the executable does not. Started when I upgraded to alpine linux 3.14 (from 3.11)